# Restore default permissions on /dev/pts

Tags: permissions, pts

Hey guys I tried to activate multiuser for some screens so I used

```
screen -A -m -d -S test
screen -S stest -X multiuser on
screen -S test -X acladd testuser
```

But I got

```
chmod /dev/pts/17: Permission denied
```

Unfortunately I thought it would be a great idea to play around with the permissions.

Now I´m with the folder it self

```
drwxrw-rw- 2 root sys            0 Jul 10 09:39 pts
```

And the files inside with the following

```
total 0 
crw-rw-rw- 1 root   sys         136,  0 Aug  4 22:30 0
crw-rw-rw- 1 markus mTeam 136,  1 Aug  1 23:20 1
crw-rw-rw- 1 markus mTeam 136, 10 Jul 24 13:47 10
crw-rw-rw- 1 markus mTeam 136, 11 Jul 27 17:43 11
crw-rw-rw- 1 markus mTeam 136, 12 Aug  4 22:33 12
crw-rw-rw- 1 markus mTeam 136, 13 Aug  4 22:32 13
crw-rw-rw- 1 markus mTeam 136, 14 Aug  4 22:33 14
crw-rw-rw- 1 markus mTeam 136, 15 Jul 27 20:12 15
crw-rw-rw- 1 markus mTeam 136, 16 Aug  4 21:46 16
crwxrwxrwx 1 markus mTeam 136, 17 Aug  4  2021 17
crw-rw-rw- 1 markus mTeam 136, 18 Aug  4 22:07 18
crw-rw-rw- 1 markus mTeam 136, 19 Aug  4 16:29 19
crw-rw-rw- 1 markus mTeam 136,  2 Jul 27 17:43 2
crw-rw-rw- 1 markus mTeam 136, 20 Jul 27 17:37 20
crw-rw-rw- 1 markus mTeam 136, 22 Jul 27 17:43 22
crw-rw-rw- 1 markus mTeam 136, 23 Aug  1 20:16 23
crw-rw-rw- 1 markus mTeam 136, 24 Aug  4 17:55 24
crw-rw-rw- 1 markus mTeam 136, 25 Jul 27 17:43 25
crw-rw-rw- 1 markus mTeam 136, 28 Jul 27 12:29 28
crw-rw-rw- 1 markus mTeam 136, 29 Jul 27 17:43 29
crw-rw-rw- 1 markus mTeam 136,  3 Aug  4 22:24 3
crw-rw-rw- 1 markus mTeam 136, 31 Jul 27 17:43 31
crw-rw-rw- 1 markus mTeam 136, 33 Jul 27 17:43 33
crw-rw-rw- 1 markus mTeam 136,  4 Aug  4 22:33 4
crw-rw-rw- 1 markus mTeam 136,  5 Jul 13 10:01 5
crw-rw-rw- 1 markus mTeam 136,  6 Aug  4 22:14 6
crw-rw-rw- 1 markus mTeam 136,  7 Aug  4 22:14 7
crw-rw-rw- 1 markus mTeam 136,  8 Aug  4 22:33 8
crw-rw-rw- 1 markus mTeam 136,  9 Jul 10 09:41 9
crw-rw-rw- 1 root   sys           5,  2 Jul 10 09:39 ptmx
```

On some other pages I have read that the permissions can change and aren't static.

And my problem is now that since I changed the permissions I'm not able to create new screens nor operate them.

When I use for example:

```
screen -A -m -S test
```

I get

```
Cannot open /dev/pts/27: Permission denied
```

So is there a way to fix my stupid mistake?

I'm grateful for every help I get :)

I'm using Ubuntu 20.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the `x` permission bit for anyone other than root, the `/dev/pts` directory is inaccessible for regular users.

Start with:

```
sudo chmod a+rx /dev/pts
```

Note that `/dev` and `/dev/pts` are RAM-based: any changes you make to them won't persist over a reboot, unless you make an udev rule or something else to re-apply your changes. So a simple reboot would also undo your mistake.

Comment: Thanks! Rebooting worked well <3